# Как работать с промежуточной таблицей для связывания моделей ManyToManyField в Django?

Tags: django

Есть две модели Courses и Teachers. Они связаны отношением ManyToManyField. В ДБ есть промежуточная таблица courses_ct. Как во views.py отобразить всех учителей для каждого курса.

models.py

```
    class Teachers(models.Model):
        SUBJECTS = (
            ('Math','Math'),
            ('Infomatics', 'Informatics'),
            ('History', 'History'),
            ('Physics', 'Physics'),
       )
        teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
        teacher_subject = models.CharField(max_length = 10, null = True, choices = SUBJECTS)
        teacher_info = models.TextField(null = True)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'teacher'
            verbose_name_plural = 'teachers'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.teacher_name

    class Courses(models.Model):
        SUBJECTS = (
            ('Math','Math'),
            ('Infomatics', 'Informatics'),
            ('History', 'History'),
            ('Physics', 'Physics'),
       )
        STATE = (
            ('A', 'Active'),
            ('N', 'Not active'),
              )
        course_title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        course_description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        course_active = models.BooleanField()
        course_full_info = models.TextField()
        course_start = models.DateField(null = True)
        course_end = models.DateField(null = True)
        course_subject = models.CharField(max_length = 10, null = True, choices = SUBJECTS)
        ct = models.ManyToManyField(Teachers, null = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря для чего это нужно, если отрендерить в шаблоне, то это можно сделать прям там:

```
{% for course in courses %}

    {% for teacher in course.ct.all %}
      {{ teacher.teacher_name }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Нужно не забыть передать курсы в контексте рендера: [доп. контекст в Class-based View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context).

Если есть потребность в обработке данных прям во вьюхе:

```
teachers = dict()

for course in Courses.objects.all():
    # имя как ключ:
    teachers[course.course_title] = course.ct.all()
    # либо ID как ключ словаря:
    # teachers[course.pk] = course.ct.all()

# Краткий вариант записи:
# teachers = { course.course_title: course.ct.all() for course in Courses.objects.all() }
```